# sed find Nth occurrence

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following string on a Linux-based synology platform, and I want to extract some values:

```
{"report":"Instantaneous values:<BR>voltage=243.5 Vrms<BR>FFTComponents:<BR>Phase 1:<BR>\tcurrent=0.348 A, activePower=68.461 W, reactivePower=50.175 var, apparentPower=84.879 VA, cosfi=80, quadrant=0, phaseshift=0.0, phaseDiff=0.0<BR>\tFFTComponents:<BR>Phase 2:<BR>\tcurrent=0.076 A, activePower=2.888 W, reactivePower=18.492 var, apparentPower=18.717 VA, cosfi=10, quadrant=0, phaseshift=0.0, phaseDiff=0.0<BR>\tFFTComponents:<BR>Phase 3:<BR>\tcurrent=1.431 A, activePower=299.807 W, reactivePower=177.96 var, apparentPower=348.646 VA, cosfi=85, quadrant=0, phaseshift=0.0, phaseDiff=0.0<BR>\tFFTComponents:<BR><BR><BR>Phase 1, peak active power 5570.098 W at 03/09/2022 14:18:10<BR>Phase 2, peak active power
4562.172 W at 25/09/2022 09:21:45<BR>Phase 3, peak active power 3188.103 W at 07/11/2022 16:35:35<BR>active energy RMS per phase mapping combination<BR>phase mapping 210=372.779 kWh [ 1/1]<BR>phase mapping 12=808.956 kWh [* 1/3]<BR>phase mapping 21=307.154 kWh [
-1/1]<BR>phase mapping 102=321.293 kWh [ -1/2]<BR>phase mapping 120=508.832 kWh [ 1/0]<BR>phase mapping 201=317.701 kWh [
-1/1]<BR><BR>active energy RMS (solar) per phase mapping combination<BR>phase mapping 210=0.0 kWh [ 1/1]<BR>phase mapping 12=0.0 kWh [* 1/3]<BR>phase mapping 21=0.0 kWh [ -1/1]<BR>phase mapping 102=0.0 kWh [ -1/2]<BR>phase mapping 120=0.0 kWh [ 1/0]<BR>phase mapping 201=0.0 kWh [ -1/1]<BR><BR>"}
```

I found some code on the internet. The code works, however, it does not give me all the information I want.

https://github.com/apazga/smappee-domoticz-bash/blob/master/smappee_bash_extractor.sh

The part of the code uses `sed` to find the string `urrent=`, and return the value after this string.

```
AMPS=`echo $SMAP |sed -e 's|.*urrent=\(.*\)|\1|' -e 's|\(.\{1,4\}\).*|\1|'`
```

I would like to split this out into AMPSL1, AMPSL2 and AMPSL3

- AMPL1: must the search for the first occurrence of current and return 0.348
- AMPL2: must the search for the second occurrence of current and return 0.076
- AMPL3: must the search for the third occurrence of current and return 1.431

I already found out that following code returns the last occurrence

```
  AMPSL3=`echo $SMAP |sed -e '$s|.*urrent=\(.*\)|\1|' -e 's|\(.\{1,4\}\).*|\1|'`
```

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: I guess you mean "third" for AMPS3? The immediate problem is that `.*` matches the entire rest of the string; you want to restrict this regex to match only ... what you want to match. More fundamentally, trying to parse free-form HTML fragments out of JSON seems like a position you would like to avoid ending up in in the first place.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: This is a linux based system (Synology). That read the string from a energy monitor called "Smappee".
The AMPSL3 must indeed return the third occurance. I il change in the text. Thanks for that.

Is there an easy way to do this with the code supplied? Can yo please give an example? I have never heard of SED before viewing and trying to extend this code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with regular expressions is they cannot count.  So you would need a different, complicated, regular expression for each value you want to extract.  Instead, I would use `grep` before `sed` to isolate the desired values:

```
$ AMPS=$(echo "$SMAP" | grep -oE 'current=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | sed -E 's|current=||')
$ echo "$AMPS"
0.348
0.076
1.431
```

Then combinations of `head` and `tail` can be used to extract the individual values.

```
$ AMPSL1=$(echo "$AMPS" | head -1)
$ echo $AMPSL1
0.348
$ AMPSL2=$(echo "$AMPS" | tail +2 | head -1)
$ echo $AMPSL2
0.076
$ AMPSL3=$(echo "$AMPS" | tail +3 | head -1)
$ echo $AMPSL3
1.431
```

Or as terdon suggests, "you could avoid the double head/tail if you use `awk`".

```
$ AMPSL2=$(echo "$AMPS" | awk 'NR==2')
$ echo $AMPSL2
0.076
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using a synology system, so will likely not have a grep that supports `-o`.

Comment: I don't know what version they were introduced, but `busybox grep` has `-o` and `-E` available, but not `-P`.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks. Fair enough, busybox is indeed the most likely one there.

Comment: You could avoid the double head/tail if you use awk, by the way. Something like `AMPL2=$(echo "$AMPS" | awk 'NR==2')`.

Comment: @terdon `grep` on my Synology NAS is GNU `grep` 3.1 from 2017, which supports `-o`.  The user does not say what Synology system they are using though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `grep` (you might not, on an embedded system), you can do this:

```
read ampl1 ampl2 ampl3 < <(grep -oP 'current=\K[0-9.]+' <<<"$amps" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\n/' )
```

The `read var < <(command)` idiom allows you to save the output of `command` into the variable `var` in your current shell using process substitution.

That is using `grep -o` to print only the matching part of the input, and `-P` for PCRE regular expressions which give us the `\K` symbol for "forget everything matched until here". We then need to convert spaces to newlines with `tr` and add a trailing newline with `sed` to get everything ready to be passed to the `read` builtin that stores into variables. The output is:

```
$ read ampl1 ampl2 ampl3 < <(grep -oP 'current=\K[0-9.]+' <<<"$amps" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/$/\n/' )
$ echo "AMPL1: $ampl1 AMPL2: $ampl2 AMPL3: $ampl3"
AMPL1: 0.348 AMPL2: 0.076 AMPL3: 1.431
```

If you can't use `grep -oP`, you can do something like this instead:

```
$ read ampl1 ampl2 ampl3 < <(perl -007 -ne '@m=(/current=([0-9.]+)/g); print "@m\n"' a)
$ echo "AMPL1: $ampl1 AMPL2: $ampl2 AMPL3: $ampl3"
AMPL1: 0.348 AMPL2: 0.076 AMPL3: 1.431
```

---

This answer requires you to use the `bash` shell.  Since the default shell on Synology systems is the `bash` shell running in POSIX mode, process substitutions (`<(...)`) are not enabled. You would have to first start `bash` by simply typing `bash`.

Or, if you will be using these commands in a script, run the script with `bash scriptName.sh`.